# Compilation error using Java generics and interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I'm attempting to make a Repository interface, that our business logic can use, with the idea that if we decide to change the data source that backs the repositories, that the business logic would not be affected. We have many clients that would be using this library, so we have begun making a suite of controllers that can be reused among clients. This is the repository interface:

```
package //redacted

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public interface Repository<T extends Object, R extends RepositoryQuery<T>> {

  T add(T entity);

  Collection<T> add(Collection<T> entities);

  void remove(T entity);

  Collection<T> getAll();

  T get(Integer id) throws InvalidEntryException;

  List<T> get(Collection<Integer> ids);

  List<T> query(R query);

  List<T> query(T query);
}
```

This is the controller I'm having problems with:

```
package //redacted

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import /* redacted */.entities.pointbank.PointBankBalance;
import /* redacted */.entities.user.User;
import /* redacted */.queries.PendingPointsBalance;
import /* redacted */.repository.Repository;
import /* redacted */.repository.RepositoryQuery;

public class RetrievePendingPointBalance { 

  private Repository<PointBankBalance, ? extends RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>> repository;
  private Constructor<? extends PendingPointsBalance> pendingQuery;

  public RetrievePendingPointBalance(Repository<PointBankBalance, ? extends RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>> repository,
          Constructor<? extends PendingPointsBalance> pendingQuery) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.pendingQuery = pendingQuery;
  }

  public PointBankBalance execute(User user) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
      PendingPointsBalance query = pendingQuery.newInstance();
      query.setUser(user);
      return repository.query(query).get(0);
  }

}
```

I'm trying to create RepositoryQuery, which is what will be responsible for handling more than just CRUD operations. Here is the interface for that:

```
package //redacted

import java.util.List;

public interface RepositoryQuery<T extends Object> {

    List<T> execute();
}
```

The idea there, is that each query can extend can extend the interface with setters for the parameters it will need. Then each implementation can extend that query interface with specifics of what it will need (example: setJdbcTemplate(...) )

On the controller above though, the line:

```
      return repository.query(query).get(0);
```

is a compilation error, and I do not know why. Is my approach inherently flawed, or am I just missing something?

Full Error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/redacted/src/main/java/com/redacted/controllers/RetrievePendingPointBalance.java:[26,28] no suitable method found for query(com.redacted.queries.PendingPointsBalance)
    method com.redated.repository.Repository.query(capture#1 of ? extends com.redated.repository.RepositoryQuery<com.redacted.entities.pointbank.PointBankBalance>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; com.redacted.queries.PendingPointsBalance cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends com.redacted.repository.RepositoryQuery<com.redacted.entities.pointbank.PointBankBalance>)
    method com.redacted.repository.Repository.query(com.redacted.entities.pointbank.PointBankBalance) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; com.redacted.queries.PendingPointsBalance cannot be converted to com.redacted.entities.pointbank.PointBankBalance)
```

And my error from Eclipse:[image]

Edit: PointBankBalance interface

```
package //redacted

import com./* redacted */.entities.pointbank.PointBankBalance;
import com./* redacted */.entities.user.User;
import com./* redacted */.repository.RepositoryQuery;

public interface PendingPointsBalance extends RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance> {

    void setUser(User user);

}
```

Comment: Post the full error message please

Comment: You don't have to specify bounds on your type parameters. If you don't have anything more specific to say than `T extends Object`, you can just put `T`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels should have been in my original post. I've added it.

Comment: What's the relationship (if any) between PendingPointsBalance and PointBankBalance?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem PointBankBalance is just a POJO, an entity. PendingPointsBalance will be the controller that returns a PointBankBalance of the pending points in the system. Right now it is only an interface. It will be different based on what implementation is called for. The goal is to have many implementations, mysql, postgres, or an external api, etc.

Comment: In that case, what you're doing makes no sense.  You are passing a PendingPointsBalance to a method that expects either a PointBankBalance or a RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>.  Your comment suggests that that is inappropriate.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I'm hitting the edge of my knowledge. I'm not sure how it would expect a PointBankBalance. It should, to how I'm thinking, accept a RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>, which is an interface that PendingPointsBalance extends.

Comment: Right.  When I asked you the relationship between PendingPointsBalance and PointBankBalance, that's what I meant - that the former is a RepositoryQuery of the latter.  So it sounds like you either need to change the type of `repository` from `Repository<PointBankBalance, ? extends RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>>` to `Repository<PointBankBalance, PendingPointsBalance>`, or change the type  of `query` from `PendingPointsBalance` to `? extends RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>`.  The latter should be a supertype of the former, not a subtype.

Comment: It could be that you do too much wildcards. Do you need to write `Repository<PointBankBalance, ? extends RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>> repository` for your other code to compile or does everything compile if you write `Repository<PointBankBalance, RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>> repository` (for the constructor argument and for the field)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the method takes an `R` and you defined `R` as `? extends RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>` in the `repository` field declaration. It's uncertain which subclass `?` refers to, so the compiler won't let you use a specific one. You could potentially set that field to an instance of `Repository<PointBankBalance, AnotherPointsBalance>`, in which case `PendingPointsBalance` wouldn't be a valid argument to its `query` method.

One way to fix it would be replacing `Repository<PointBankBalance, ? extends RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>>` with `Repository<PointBankBalance, PendingPointsBalance>`.

Or you could simplify things by removing the `R` parameter entirely:

```
public interface Repository<T extends Object> {

    ...

    List<T> query(RepositoryQuery<T> query);

    List<T> query(T query);
}
```

Then just replace `Repository<PointBankBalance, ? extends RepositoryQuery<PointBankBalance>>` with `Repository<PointBankBalance>`.